# Cant get session to store, what am I missing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

So I've got this form where users signs his ass up. When the user filled in all the details, he clicks on the submit button. An Ajax request submits the form and puts all the details in the database. If that has happen without any errors, a hidden div with two (payments) buttons opens up. After clicking on the iDeal or PayPal button, colorbox opens up and show the 'overview-page'. Now I'd like to show the users information from the database via $_SESSION['user_id']. But somehow, I'm not storing the session orso as the 'overview-page' is empty.

I'm not sure what I'm missing, any heads up would be awesome!

**This is the form:**

```
<div class="content main container" id="goShowOrderForm">
<div class="content main box">
<div id="udidOrderForm" class="order form">
<form action="post" id="orderForm" name="form">

<label for="email">Email</label>
<input type="email" class="input-fullwidth" name="email">

<div class="two-column">
<label for="password">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="password">
</div>

<div class="two-column right">
<label for="repassword">Confirm Password</label>
<input type="password" name="re_password">
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="token" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['guest_token'] ?>">

</form>

<div class="orderFormActions">
<input type="submit" class="button darkblue order" name="submitNewStep" id="submitNewStep" value="Nu afrekenen">
<div class="button red cancel" id="cancelUdidOrder">Afbreken</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

**Ajax post page (to store data in db after submit)**

```
<?php
include '../includes/database/db_connect.php';
include '../includes/database/functions.php';

if($_POST) {

//Form data
$email = safe($mysqli,$_POST['email']); 
$guestToken = safe($mysqli,$_POST['token']); 

$password = veilig($mysqli,$_POST['password']);
$rePassword = veilig($mysqli,$_POST['re_password']);

//Check if everything has been filled in correctly
if ($email == '' || $password == '' || $rePassword == '')  {    
echo "orderFormRequiredFields";
exit();
}

//Check emailFormat
if (!CheckEmailFormat($email)) {
echo "orderFormerrorEmailFormat";
exit();
}

//Check if email already exist
$checkIfEmailExist = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$email'");
if (mysqli_num_rows($checkIfEmailExist) > 0){
echo "orderFormEmailAlreadyExist";
exit(); 
}

//Check if the two passwords do match
if ( $password == $rePassword ) {
//Als wachtwoorden overeen komen, maak er een hashed pw + salt van
$salt = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));
$saltedPW =  $password . $salt;
$hashedPW = hash('sha256', $saltedPW);

} else {
echo "orderFormErrorPasswordConfirm";
exit();
}


$tstamp = time();
$token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand()));
//Add user to the database
$createUser = mysqli_query($mysqli,"INSERT INTO members (account_active, email, guest_token, password, salt) 
VALUES ('0', '$email', '$guestToken', '$hashedPW', '$salt'); ");


//begin storing user_id
//Check for the users salt
$getSalt = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT salt FROM members WHERE email = '$email';");

if (!$getSalt) {
echo "Error Salt";
exit();
} 

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getSalt);
$salt = $row['salt'];


//Find the user details
$saltedPW =  $password . $salt;
$hashedPW = hash('sha256', $saltedPW);
$findUser = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE email = '$email' AND password = '$hashedPW'");
$roww = mysqli_fetch_assoc($findUser);
$user_id = $roww['user_id'];

//If users exist, count should be 1
$count = mysqli_num_rows($findUser);

if($count == 1) {
$_SESSION['user_id'] = $user_id; 
$_SESSION['email'] = $email;
} else {
echo "Error";
exit();
}
//end

echo "succesMsgOrderForm";
}
?>
```

**This is the basic of the overview page**

```
<?php
include 'includes/database/db_connect.php';
include 'includes/database/functions.php';

sec_session_start();

$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];

$getAllDetails = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM members WHERE user_id = '$user_id' ") OR die (mysqli_error($mysqli));
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($getAllDetails);
$email = $row['email'];

?>
<body>
user_id is: <?php echo $user_id ?> <br>
email is: <?php echo $email ?>
</body>
```

Thank you,

**Edit #1 sec_session_start() part which is in functions.php:**

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = SECURE;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    session_name($session_name);
    session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
    session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 
}
```

**Edit #2 - Part where I open up the colorbox (javascript)**

```
$(document).on('click', '#pay_ideal', function(){
    $.colorbox({
        width: 500,
        height: 350,
        speed: 350,
        closeButton: false,
        href:"order-overview.php"
    });
});
```

Comment: code for `sec_session_start();`?

Comment: Sorry about that. Just edited my question. The sec_session_start part has been edited.

Comment: You said that you are not storing session, but you already stored that sessio. Please post your code that opens colorbox

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL I have edited my question. Code included.

Comment: When you try to open overview page it is loading `order-overview.php` page. Could you please tell me the output of `var_dump($user_id)` after `$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];` ? I just want to be sure on your session started correctly

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL It returns NULL

Comment: and what about `var_dump($_SESSION)` ?

Comment: @HüseyinBABAL empty, results: 
array(0) { }

Comment: You need to check session status before refreshing your session. I have updated your `sec_session_start` function.  See my answer further detail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check session status before refreshing your session lik;

```
function sec_session_start() {
    $session_name = 'sec_session_id';   // Set a custom session name
    $secure = SECURE;
    // This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
    $httponly = true;
    // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
    ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1);
    // Gets current cookies params.
    $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
    session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"],
        $cookieParams["path"], 
        $cookieParams["domain"], 
        $secure,
        $httponly);
    // Sets the session name to the one set above.
    if (session_id() == '') {
        session_name($session_name);
        session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
        session_regenerate_id();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have replaced this with the one I had. It's not loading the overview page anymore and give a GET http://domain.com/order-overview.php 500 (Internal Server Error)  error

Comment: Please tell me the exact error. And Which version of PHP do you use?

Comment: exact error: GET http://domain.com/order-overview.php 500 (Internal Server Error) jquery.js:7845 (consolelog). Colorbox cannot open the content. I'm using the newest PHP

Comment: Ok you are right colorbox cannot open becaues php page gets error. You need to check error log or ajax response in network tab in firebug console

Comment: Ok, that is because you have error on php page. Try to go to overview page diretly on browser. And what is the error written on page?

Comment: Edit: The page is completely empty. When I open up console of chrome and refresh the page, I get the same GET error for like 1 second.

Comment: Ok at the top of your page, insert this after `<?php`    `error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: /includes/database/config.php on line 10 Fatal error: Call to undefined function session_status() in includes/database/functions.php on line 19

Comment: Also re-checked my PHP version: 5.3.28

Comment: Ok see my updated code. If you use < php 5.4.x you cannot use `session_status`. Check my answer for corrected one.

Comment: Thanks! The page opens now into Colorbox, but the var_dump($user_id); still returns NULL and var_dump($_SESSION); returns empty array :(

Comment: İt is because, you are setting session in registering part. First you fill the form and press submit. Session will be declared and after that you can open overview page

Comment: And what do you recommend me to do? I mean, I want the user to sign up the form, click submit. Everything has been inserted into the database. If that has been without any problems, a hidden div shows itself. Click on the paypal payment button, colorbox opens and there should be an active session..

Comment: After successfull submit and db insert, you can store user id in session. You can get user id after db insert. And then enable payment div

Comment: That is exactly how I'm doing it right now, correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: Yes. The Array is still empty.

Comment: You need to put `sec_session_start` in register php also. Put that function at the top of ajax post php and try again. In register page, you are trying to set session without session_start